# Core Data filter to many ordered relationship with predicate

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate, nsfetchrequest

I have a Core Data model with Task and List, where List has a to-many ordered relationship to Task, and Task has the inverse to-many relationship to List. I need to retrieve Tasks from a given List in the correct order, but filtered to match a predicate. For example, if `priority` is a field on Task,

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithString:@"priority == HIGH"]

List* list; // already fetched
```

I can accomplish it by

```
NSArray* allTasks = list.tasks;
NSArray* someTasks = [allTasks filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

but that requires pulling all the tasks into memory. I could just fetch the tasks directly

```
NSFetchRequest* req = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Task"];
[req setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"list == %@ AND priority == HIGH", list]];
NSArray* someTasks = [context executeFetchRequest:req error:&error];
```

but then the task order is not preserved.

Is there a way to filter the relationship fault by a predicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following method will work, though it is very inefficient:

1. Fetch the required `Tasks` using your desired predicate, ensuring that the fetch request's `returnsObjectsAsFaults` property is set to true.
2. Create a new predicate with format "SELF IN %@", passing the array of tasks (from step 1) as the argument.
3. Filter the ordered set (`list.tasks`) using the new predicate.

That way the predicate is evaluated in the store, without faulting in the tasks, while the order is still determined by the ordered relationship.

Comment: Interesting. Theoretically this is O(n^2), but since list.tasks is still a fault, I wonder if core data optimizes it by combining the predicates

Comment: I doubt it, sadly.  The predicate at step 2 knows nothing of how the array of Tasks was derived.  But I think CD will do the minimum by comparing the primary keys, without faulting-in the Task objects.

Comment: True, still more efficient than firing the faults. Thanks for your answer. I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using an ordered relationship, `Task` entities are not going to come back in any specific order unless you put a sort on the `NSFetchRequest`.

I would suggest adding a sort to the `NSFetchRequest` and sort by what is giving you your order of the tasks.  Then they will come back in a consistent order.

As an aside, **NEVER** pass `nil` to the `error:` parameter.  That is just going to hide a potential error in the future.

Comment: I'm using an ordered relationship  List --to-many-ordered--> Tasks

Comment: Do the tasks have a natural order or is the order purely user controlled?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. They are user controlled. I could manually store a sortValue field on Task, but I don't think that would work for a many-to-many relationship with List. It is also difficult to maintain

Comment: On a many to many you would need to turn the hidden join table into a real object. It is a small amount of pain but there is the trade off that the sort values are exposed to your business logic.  This is different than an ordered relationship where the order is hidden from you and leaving you only the option that you started with :/